# Why are there so many moving parts used in the landing gear?

Tags: aircraft-design, landing-gear

[This](https://youtu.be/pkv81Er5VKg) short clip of the landing gear on a Hawker 850XP being retracted seems extremely complex.

[image: YouTube video frame]

I'm curious to know why there are so many moving parts but as a layman I'm struggling to make sense of it all.

So what exactly is going on here and why?

Comment: A good guess is some kind of complicated way of folding it into the compartment.

Comment: Compared to other landing gear I've seen, this is relatively *uncomplicated*.  You might want to edit it into a generic question rather than about the Hawker since your opening premise is wrong.

Comment: @simon, I'm open to suggestions as to how this can be changed. What would you say it is relatively uncomplicated compared to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

One of the key points (circled in red) above shows the part that locks the gear in the extended position and requires that the linkage up top (circled in blue) is actuated to release the gear.

At the end of the clip you can see a glimpse of the linkage bar at the top returning to its previous position. That way if the gear is dropped by gravity it will lock itself once fully deployed.

If you strip those parts all that's left is a basic 4-bar linkage and a connection to the gear door.